# Wrap content using simple regex

Tags: jquery, regex, text

I'm trying to use regex to wrap some content in a class called '.info'

```
 <div id="content">
content content content content content

INFO Information content information content ENDINFO
</div>​
```

Here is my start.

```
 $(document)ready(function(){
var content = $('#content').html();
var regex = /INFO.*ENDINFO/gi;
var info = content.match(regex);

$('.INFO').html(info);
});​
```

The intended result:

```
 <div id="content">
content content content content content

<div class="info"> Information content information content </div>
</div>​
```

What could be an alternative to regex? I'm unfamiliar with `.find` attribute, but would this work?

Comment: You know about [**wrap**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) right?

Comment: Is there another way to find and wrap something based on raw text?

Comment: Could you post you intended result? Regexs are nice features but they tend to be a bit slow. Maybe there is a faster/cleaner/better solution to you problem. Also, does it need to be a client side solution? Server side string parsing is usually a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Nebula, avoiding regex would great. Client side I believe, using a CMS thats out of my control.

Comment: @uriah Hm ok, and the INFO and ENDINFO are there because you can't use regular HTML I assume. Also, you can use cre javascript to find a substring: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-index-of-string/ But when the regex doesn't hurt you page performance I'd say "go with the answers provided".

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex to:

```
var regex = /INFO(.*)ENDINFO/gi;
$('.INFO').html(info[1]);
```

It's called capturing class.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do it with regex try this:

```
$('#content').html(content.replace(/info(.*)endinfo/gi, 
   '<span class="info">$1</span>'));
```

Comment: could you please update this fiddle. I can't seem to get it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/pSGBg/1/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow.

Comment: He means the error console of you browser (ctrl+shift+j in forefox) it says 

Timestamp: 9/20/2012 11:28:16 AM
Error: Error: Permission denied to access property 'replace'
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pSGBg/3/show/
Line: 20